# Apache: Caching a DEFLATE'd file

Tags: apache, caching, compression, mod-deflate

It seems redundant to have zlib compress a web page during every request. It is also the bottleneck of my files' response times. Is there a way to cache the zlib'd file so that it is compressed only once at each modification? Or should I just keep wishing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want a quick and lazy solution, just make gzipped copies of your most used files and turn [MultiViews](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/content-negotiation.html) on for them. This still has CPU overhead to calculate the right file to send but it's less than a gzip every time. If you want to take it further you can create static type-map files.

Also you could consider using Lighttpd if possible instead of Apache. It has a mod_compress which does exactly what you want.

Answer (score 2):

Hm, I think mod_cache will do the job. http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_cache.html